# Default screen temperature in Gnome

Tags: gnome, screen

I can configure the screen temperature to be always 4000 for example by using this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.color active true
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.color night-light-enabled true
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.color night-light-temperature 4000
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.color night-light-schedule-automatic false
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.color night-light-schedule-from 0
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.color night-light-schedule-to 24
```

My problem is that some programs reset the screen temperature. It is annoying. And it means that there is another variable which contains the default screen temperature.

> What is this variable please ?